# Inject constant param form getter in twig

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony4

I have defined constant in my entity like:

```
$fieldName = User::METADATA_OF_USER
```

It's passed as the entity getter param:

```
public function getMetaDataField($fieldName)
{
    $metadata = json_decode($this->metadata, true);

    return $metadata[$fieldName] ?? null;
}
```

When I try to pass it in twig:

```
{ item.metadataField }}
```

it requires that fieldName param as constant.

I tried some solution of twig constants but non of them worked for me. I there any way to inject that constant in the view?

Comment: `I tried some solution of twig constants` - Well you should add these to your question first then

Comment: If it's constant, why provide a parameter for it in the first place? Just change the signature to `getMetaDataField()`. Unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Twig documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/functions/constant.html), you need to use the `constant` function :

```
{{ item.getMetaDataField(constant('Namespace\\User::METADATA_OF_USER')) }}
// or
{{ item.getMetaDataField(constant('METADATA_OF_USER', instance)) }}
```

Note the `\\`.